# Cocoa - Prevent System from shutting down

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Hey Guys,
I've another question I couldn't find an answer on the internet. I hope you can help me.

I'm writing an Cocoa Application which runs in background and does several tasks for me. If I quit the application, I show a NSAlert. That all works great. But here comes my problem. This Alert is presented from inside the `applicationShouldTerminate:` Method. So if I Logout, this method is triggered and the alert is shown. But OSX quits the application and logs out without waiting for a response even if I return `NSTerminateCancel`.

How can I force the OS to stop logging out/shutting down from within my application, so that the user (myself :-D) can decide what to do. (It just a dialog which asks if the done work shall be saved or not.)

I hope you can help me...

Sandro

Comment: No. Because I didn't need one anymore. So I stopped searching. But I think that the answer of mu96 should do it. Have a look at that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X is based on UNIX. When a system shuts down, the SIGKILL signal is send that terminates all the processes. But before that, the SIGTERM signal is sent that informs the processes that a shutdown is going to take place.

I think the solution lies in handling of the signals, i.e. detecting and blocking them. Regarding this, you may find guidance in [GNU C Library: Signal Handling: Blocking Signals.](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/glibc-manual-0.02/library_toc.html#SEC368)

The examples there maybe about BSD, but you may know that the OS X core is derived from BSD and therefore OS X supports it. Moreover, C is supported in Objective-C.